# Merge many small polygons into larger shapes

Tags: gdal, land-cover, polygonize

I'm trying to build a landcover layer from the [ESA Land Cover](https://www.esa-landcover-cci.org/) dataset. So far, I have been able to convert the image data to a bunch of very small polygons. But for my use, I really just want a "general" overview of the landcover shapes.

Are there any good strategies for taking these many small sized polygons and merging them into larger, more generic low-poly shapes?

The data I'm converting is going from GeoTIFF -> GeoJSON via [GDAL polygonize](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html).

[image]

Comment: Please mention a preferred software or programming language.

Comment: Vector *tiling* is all about making small tiles of your data, what exactly do you not want? :D

Comment: @Padmanabha I'm open to any, this is really just about cleaning up the data.

Comment: @bugmenot123 The data right now is very detailed (millions of small polygons, with gaps between them). I'm really just looking for the general shape of the layers, basically merging all the many small ones into larger, lower fidelity ones.

Comment: I think you want to look at raster to polygon tools instead of creating tiles.

Comment: @jbalk Yeah, maybe my question wasn't clear. I am doing raster (geotiff) -> polygon (geojson) right now, and that's probably where things are going wrong. Tiles are sort of besides the point (though eventually these will be served via tiles). This should probably just focus on the polygonization.

Comment: You want to union the polygons after you create them, group by landcover.  If you want single part polygons, you'll need to dump the unioned polygons or do multipart to singlepart operation.  The union will give you 1 multipolygon for each landcover type.

Comment: Follow it all up with a simplification pass.  That may be tricky as you'll probably end up with overlapping polygons unless you use topology of some sort.

Comment: Are there gaps between the polygons?  If so, you'll need a strategy to deal with those gaps first.